# array comparison using php

Tags: php, arrays

Code does not stop running.i need to compare the two arrays in order to match each string.  two arrays with different sizes.

First array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => '+2+x=1' 
    [1] => '+x+2=1' 
    [2] => 'x+2=1' 
    [3] => '-1+2=7' 
    [4] => '+2-1=7' 
    [5] => '+x+27=3+2' 
    [6] => 'x+27=3+2' 
    [7] => 'x=3' 
    [8] => '+x=3' 
)
```

Second array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => '+x+2=1' 
    [1] => '-1+2=7' 
    [2] => '+x+27=3+2' 
    [3] => '+x=3' 
)
```

my current code: (first array  = $step_1, second array = $arr_result)

```
$count1 = 0;

for ($k=0; $k < count($arr_result); $i++) {
    for ($l=0; $l < count($step_1); $l++) { 
        if (strcmp($arr_result[$k],$step_1[$l]) == 0) {
            $count1++;      
            echo "$k "."$l ".strcmp($arr_result[$k],$step_1[$l])."<br>";
        }  
    }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-intersect.php), it will return an array with the matching values of both arrays :

```
$array1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'abc'];  
$array2 = ['foo', 123, 456, 789, 4654, 'abcdef'];

$matching_values = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

$matching_values will result in

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
)
```

**Edit: Notice that in your FOR you use $k but you increment $i... That's why your code doesn't stop;**

> for ($k=0; $k < count($arr_result); $i++)